# How to use Google Picker with Google Drive using flutter

Tags: google-picker

I can't find any resource to embed google Picker in a flutter to upload a doc to Google drive. Can any provide me with an example of how to integrate Google Picker to Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, you can use **[file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)**:

```dart
final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
```

It will navigate user to an UI for selecting files including other app's files, i.e. google drive.

---

BTW, you should request [permissions](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) before picking the file:

```dart
final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: []);
await googleSignIn.signIn()
// request when you need it!
await googleSignIn.requestScopes([SheetsApi.spreadsheetsScope])
```

---

Found similar question here: [File Picker for Google Drive Rest API for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445168/file-picker-for-google-drive-rest-api-for-android)